# Read value in omniauth-twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I have gone through
[How to read value from params array in omniauth-twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141715/how-to-read-value-from-params-array-in-omniauth-twitter) but there is no any solution given there to access @params. Can anyone have an idea how to access them? Like @key variable given in the above post. I wanted to access key attribute in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can access it like

```
env["omniauth.auth"]["extra"]["access_token"].consumer.key
```